# How to disable the svn-update-automerge for XML files

Tags: svn, merge, svn-merge

I have the svn repo with XML files, and I'm not satisfied with svn-update automerge functionality.

After `svn update` or `svn update --accept postpone` I've got the corrupted XML like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VERSION>
<<<<<<< .mine
    <MAJOR>200</MAJOR>
=======
    <MAJOR>100</MAJOR>
>>>>>>> .r10
</VERSION>
```

SVN think XML was a text file, and place some markers for human editor here

How to disable the merge in `svn update` for XML (text) files?

I've read and try all answers in [Can I turn off automatic merging in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803/can-i-turn-off-automatic-merging-in-subversion), but it's doesn't work for SVN v 1.8.

**UPD**

I was review the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7673033/3578861, and found it's doesn't actual for svn 1.8 - `Subcommand 'update' doesn't accept option '--diff-cmd ARG'`

But now was a `diff3-cmd` option instead.

If I modify the solution to

```
svn update --accept postpone --diff3-cmd="d:\\f.bat"
```

and write `d:\f.bat` script with

```
@type %9
@exit 1
```

It's work now. But it's too much overheaded and unstable hack. This script accept the input streams from all conflicted files and save one of them to result file - it's very stupid and costly

Is there are a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better solution will be redefine MIME-type of *.xml to `some/nontext` in SVN-repository (or globally in config-file in `[auto-props]` section)?

Comment: Yes, may be, I'll try. But there is a lot of file extention for DSL XML file. SVG is an example. Can I define nontext for all files with xml content?

Comment: @Y.N - no. only *per extension*, not per context

Comment: I try to `config` `[miscellany] enable-auto-props = yes` and `[auto-props] *.xml = svn:mime-type=image/gif` or `*.xml = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream` and where is NO effect

Comment: @Y.N - autopros works only on *new* files at **adding to repository** stage. For versioned files you have to define this property by hand

Comment: Yes, now I see. After configuring autoprops or manual setting the file property to binary mime-type svn stop to merge it.

Comment: But I think. my task is not solved. How to handle the files which are already be in repo without any mime? I think this is a hack, and it's not a clear and stable solution

Comment: @Y.N - for files in repo - `svn ps svn:mime-type` **only**. In future, you can have [Repository Dictated Configuration](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/the-road-to-repository-dictated-configuration-day-2-autoprops) from start of every repo